# Can Rcpp be used to speed up calls to other R functions?

Tags: r, algorithm, optimization, rcpp

I am writing an [R package for statistical analysis and machine learning (ML)](https://tripartio.github.io/ale/) that is often very slow. It is slow because it involves training and predicting models, both statistical and machine learning. My package is model-agnostic, by which I mean that it interfaces with any other model training and prediction package from R to retrain their models and use their models to make predictions. After extensive profiling and code refactoring (mainly by converting as much as possible to vectorized and matrix operations), I have found that the slow points that I cannot speed up further by refactoring come down to code that:

- calls predict functions from other R packages. My main procedures might call the predict function literally thousands of times, so predict functions that take even 0.1 seconds can result in my functions taking many minutes or even a few hours to run.
- calls to train models from other R packages. A few of my procedures retrain the input models from 100 to 1000 times. So, model training time of 1 second takes around 17 minutes to run. Slower training time than that becomes really unmanageable.

I would like to know if [Rcpp](https://www.rcpp.org/) can help speed things up in my situation. Please note what I am not asking here:

- I am not asking about if I really need to run and predict models as many times as that. I am pursuing that important question separately; I am indeed trying to minimize those needs as much as possible. So, I am asking based on the assumption that I really do need to run models and predictions that often.
- I certainly intend to implement parallel processing to help alleviate the problem, but this is only a limited solution. Even if some users have as many as 10 physical computer cores (which very few users would have), dividing the example speeds I gave above by 10 would still result in slow code. I'm trying to go further than that. Parallel processing would be an additional solution to whatever else I can do.

**My key doubt about whether [Rcpp](https://www.rcpp.org/) can help is that the slowest code is when I call other packages' R functions.** I've been reading up a lot on Rcpp and I'm even taking [the DataCamp course on that topic](https://campus.datacamp.com/courses/optimizing-r-code-with-rcpp/). However, from my current exploration of Rcpp, although many sources explain why we would want to use Rcpp (to speed up slow R code), I have been unable to find any source that clearly spells out what kinds of problems that Rcpp cannot help with.

From what I've gathered, Rcpp cannot provide any speed-up when it calls R functions. The functions that are slowing down my code are those written by other packages. For example, I have [an article that demonstrates my package functionality](https://tripartio.github.io/ale/articles/ale-ALEPlot.html) using `nnet::nnet()` and `nnet::predict.nnet()` to train and predict a neural network, respectively, and `gbm::gbm()` and `gbm::predict.gbm()` to train and predict a gradient boosted machine, respectively. Is there any way to use Rcpp to optimize the calls to these functions?

**If I could call `Rcpp::cppFunction()` in real-time to receive these functions, compile them to C++, and then continue to execute them with my program, then that could be a viable solution.** But is that even possible with Rcpp? I would appreciate any guidance here. And I am willing to accept a clearly explained answer of, "No, Rcpp cannot help in your case, and here's why."

Comment: If R function calls are slow, calling the functions from compiled code won't change the R function calls and their performance. That would require magic and we don't have that (yet?).

Comment: There is no R-to-C nor R-to-C++ transpiler. If you want to run ML algorithms that currently only exist as R code, you will need to translate them yourself. However, most of the heavy lifting in many R ML packages is already implemented in compiled code, including [nnet](https://github.com/cran/nnet/blob/master/src/nnet.c). What you are doing simply sounds compute-intensive.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It appears some aspects are being confused here:

- R code runs as R code at the speed of R code, even when called from Rcpp. There is no magic change Rcpp can effectuate that changes *the R interpreter*.
- C++ code runs as the speed of compiled code, which is generally faster and sometimes *a lot faster*
- One can mix and match: C++ code *can* call R code via for example `Rcpp::Function`. It is documented that this used to have more prohibitive overhead in very early days (and that is what the previous answer refers to) but got (much !!) better several years ago (see release NEWS or ChangeLog). There is still some overhead, but it is entirely viable and many packages to that for *some* tasks (including Rcpp itself).
- One generally does not want to call `cppFunction()` repeatedly, or at each start of a package: when Rcpp code helps, it is trivial to wrap it in a package.
- One can also mix and match, there are packages passing compiled functions to R functions.

Most importantly, it generally pays off to follow a general rule: do not conjecture but rather profile and measure.

Comment: (+1) FWIW, I actually don't think the OP was confusing these aspects; I'm betting the whole reason (s)he asked this question is that (s)he didn't see how Rcpp could possibly make it faster to run R code, but (s)he came across claims that Rcpp lets you speed up your R code, so (s)he wanted to make sure that those claims meant only the thing that makes sense and not what they actually sound like.

Comment: @ruakh, I wish I were as smart as you conjecture me to be, but I sincerely was fishing to see if someone has a solution to rearchitect my software so that I could perhaps use Rcpp to somehow compile R code that was not rewritten in C++. It seems from these very helpful answers that this is not (yet) possible. (The "yet" is still me dreaming.)

Answer (score 6):

According to [the article "Calling R Functions from C++", by Dirk Eddelbuettel (creator of Rcpp)](https://gallery.rcpp.org/articles/r-function-from-c++/):

> Calling a function is […] slow as there are overheads involved. And calling it repeatedly from inside your C++ code, possibly buried within several loops, is outright silly. This *has to be* slower than equivalent C++ code, and even slower than just the R code (because of the marshalling of data).

That article is eleven years old, and there's much less overhead now than there was then (hat-tip to user [Ada Lovelace](https://stackoverflow.com/users/23224962/ada-lovelace) for pointing this out), but the core point remains true: calling an R function from C++ code still has to be slower than calling the same R function from R code.

Comment: No the comment is dated and no longer correct. See eg the NEWS file for release 0.12.18.

Comment: @AdaLovelace: Thanks for that info! I've updated the answer accordingly. :-)

Comment: Good update, and 'are you sure ?' about your remaining claim?  I think calling _the same R function_ will be approximately the same speed called from R, or called from C++.  You are talking to the same underlying REPL.

Comment: Thanks for the answer and its update. The "selected answer" for me is a toss-up between  yours and Ada Lovelace (back from the dead, it seems), but hers is more detailed. I appreciate your citing Dirk Eddelbuettel, though.